# Trouble understanding filter and ultrafilter

Tags: elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra, filters

A filter F on S is a collection of subsets of S in which two conditions hold:

If A and B belong to the collection F then A∩B also belongs to the collection.
If A belongs to the collection F and A is a subset of B then B also belongs to the collection. (If A⊂B then B is said to be a superset of A.)
For S={a, b, c} one filter is the collection :
{ {a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c} }
Why is {a,c} not in the filter collection here, {a} is a subset of {a,c} so it must be in the example given above .
Can someone make me understand ultrafilter with respect to Boolean Algebra ?

Comment: In the second condition, B has to be a subset of S.  Yes, {a,c} has to be in the collection for it to be a filter of S.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed $\{a,c\}$ should be in this collection, in fact all subsets that contain $a$. On a finite set we only have filters that are generated by their intersection, as is easy to check.

A filter $\mathcal{F}$ on a Boolean algebra $B$ is a subset of $B$ obeying the conditions:

- $\emptyset \neq \mathcal{F} \neq B$
- $\forall b_1,b_2 \in B: b_1, b_2 \in \mathcal{F} \implies b_1 \land b_2 \in \mathcal{F}$.
- $\forall b_1, b_2 \in B: (b_1 \in \mathcal{F} \text{ and } b_1 \le b_2) \implies b_2 \in \mathcal{F}$.

Note the similarity to the conditions for subsets, which is not coincidental, as the powerset of $S$ is a Boolean algebra (where $\land$ is intersection and $\le$ inclusion).

In either case an ultrafilter is a filter that is maximal w.r.t  inclusion; there can be no filter that is a strict superset of it.